# Busca por inconsistência em uma lista C#

Tags: c#, lista

Boa tarde.

Tenho uma lista da classe Projeto
A classe Projeto tem as propriedades:

```
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Nome_Usuario { get; set; }
    public string Nome_Projeto { get; set; }
```

Nesta lista posso ter o mesmo ID, Nome_Usuario e Nome_Projeto  diversas vezes repetidas.

Exemplo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O nome João com ID = 1 aparece diversas vezes na minha classe, com ele posso usar o valor do campo PROJETO para atualizar outros registros que não vem ao caso.

Agora o registro do Marcos não posso usar pois ele participa de dois projetos diferentes e não pode ser usado na minha atualização.

Comment: Qual é a duvida?

Comment: Como posso ter o controle para atualizar ou não o valor do campo PROJETO seguindo as regras citadas acima.

Comment: Diversas vezes seria maior ou igual a 2 projetos iguais para cada ID?

Comment: sim. posso ter o mesmo registro diversas vezes com projetos diferentes

Comment: Eu ainda não entendi o que você quer fazer. Consegue explicar o que deseja fazer e qual é a sua dúvida de outra maneira? Talvez o problema é a minha deficiência de interpretação, sei lá...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode tentar usar o método de extensão .All(), mas terá que passar o projeto como parâmetro. Se você informar o Projeto LG na lista do João, o método irá te retornar verdadeiro e quando fizer a mesma consulta com o Projeto LG na lista do Marcos, será tornado false porque nem todos são LG. Qualquer coisa posta o código que pode ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você deva relacionar melhor suas informações. Ao que me parece, este é um caso onde existiria uma classe "Colaborador.cs":

> public string id { get; set; }
>    public string nome { get; set; }

uma classe "Projeto.cs":

> public string id { get; set; }
>      public string nome{ get; set; }

e uma classe que relacionasse ambas "Trabalhos.cs":

> public string id { get; set; }
>      public string idColaborador { get; set; }
>      public string idProjeto { get; set; }

Assim você só precisaria referenciar o id único da classe Trabalhos para fazer seu update.